# How to separate torch dataset items at the collate function phase?

Tags: python, pytorch

At times, my data set will emit output that contains two examples instead of two, owing to the length of the item.

I am wondering if, when two examples are emitted, that I can split them and count them as two batches instead of one at the collate_fn phase of the data loader, or if I have to go back to how the data was engineered and alter that?

So, for example, data that looks like this might come across:

```
batch['input_ids'] = [[[101, 2014, 2353, 2201, 1010, 1000, 102],
  [101, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 102]]]
```

When normally the data looks like this:

```
batch['input_ids'] = [[101, 109, 209, 909, 434, 543, 0]]
```

I have tried to play with a collate function which works independently, but not when you mix batches of different sizes, such as below:

```
# check output
for idx, batch in enumerate(test_ds):
    if idx == 0: break
batch['input_ids']

#[[[101, 2014, 2353, 2201, 1010, 1000, 102],
#  [101, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 102]]]

out = torch.stack([torch.as_tensor(item) for item in batch['input_ids']]).squeeze(0)
out.shape  # [2, 7]


# collate fn
def collate(batch):
    embeddings = torch.stack([torch.as_tensor(item) for item in batch['input_ids']]).squeeze(0)
    return collate

# create dataloader
test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds,
                     batch_size=2,
                     collate_fn=collate,
                     drop_last=False)

# check output
for idx, batch in enumerate(test_dl):
    if idx == 0: break

# Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is dummy code of the phenomenon:

```
# packages
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

# prepare torch data set
class torchds(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    '''
    dummy test set
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.inputs = [[[[101, 2014, 2353, 2201, 1010, 1000, 102],
                     [101, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 102]]],
                     [[101, 109, 209, 909, 434, 543, 000]]]
        return None

    # get len
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    # pull a sample of data
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
        return {'input_ids': self.inputs[idx]}

# instantiate ds
test_ds = torchds()

# check output
for idx, batch in enumerate(test_ds):
    if idx == 0: break
batch['input_ids']

out = torch.stack([torch.as_tensor(item) for item in batch['input_ids']]).squeeze(0)
out.shape



# collate fn
def collate(batch):
    embeddings = torch.stack([torch.as_tensor(item) for item in batch['input_ids']]).squeeze(0)
    return collate

# create dataloader
test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds,
                     batch_size=2,
                     collate_fn=collate,
                     drop_last=False)

# check output
for idx, batch in enumerate(test_dl):
    if idx == 0: break
batch
```

Comment: Short answer is yes you can split the data inside of `collate()` and output as two batch, but I suggest you process the dataset before put it in `DataLoader`, that gonna make data flow much tidy for later process

Comment: Thanks again for your continued insights.